# Display partial for selected controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want a chunk of code(a shopping cart) to display in my header on an index and show page for 2 controllers but not for any other parts of my app.

My current plan is to put this code in a partial, and:

```
 = render partial 'layouts/cart' if the params[:controller] == "Products" || params[:controller] == "Categories"
```

Is there a better way? I am using Rails 3.2

Answer (score 1):

(**I am using erb, I don't know haml but idea should be simply transferable**)

You can use [content_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for) to solve your problem.

Add this code to the view files you would like the cart to show up.

**Products/show.html.erb Products/index.html.erb Categories/show.html.erb,Categories/index.html.erb** ( as in your question).

```
<% content_for :cart,  render('layouts/cart') %>
```

Now call:

```
<%= yield :cart %>
```

in your **application.html.erb**(or wherever you would like cart to show up).

**EXAMPLE**:

layouts/application:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Testapp</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= yield :cart%>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

products/show:

```
<% content_for :cart,  render('layouts/cart') %>

<p>I have content_for call so my appilication.html will dispaly cart partial</p>
```

products/index:

```
<p>I don't have content_for call so my appilication.html will not dispaly cart partial</p>
```

layouts/cart:

```
<h1>Here I am!</h1>
```

visiting products index path will produce:

```
I don't have content_for call so my appilication.html will not dispaly cart partial
```

visiting products show path will produce:

```
Here I am!
I have content_for call so my appilication.html will dispaly cart partial
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything inherently wrong with what you're doing there, but if you need to put it in lots of places it could be error prone.

You could leave the

```
= render partial 'layouts/cart'
```

where you want to use it and put

```
if the params[:controller] == "Products" || params[:controller] == "Categories"
```

in the partial so you're keeping the logic in only one place

Answer (score 0):

You should try to keep logic out of your views (that includes partials). So, best way would be to offload that into a helper.

#### helpers/application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def show_cart
    render 'layouts/cart' if ['Products', 'Categories'].include?(params[:controller])
  end
end
```

#### in the view

```
<%= show_cart %>
```